# Not able to get Contacts in cordova

Tags: android, cordova

I have the below code using Cordova and Contacts plugin which was installed via CLI.

What I am trying to do is to read all contacts from my phone. With the below code, I get only one popup alert as "null" instead of the display name. Also the popup comes only once.

Config.xml and manifest file are automatically updated by CLI to include the required things.

I am using Cordova 3.5.0 version. Should I include any other JS files?

```
    <script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>   

    <script type="text/javascript">
        document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);

        function onDeviceReady() {
            var options = new ContactFindOptions();
            options.filter = "";
            var fields = ["displayName", "name"];
            navigator.contacts.find(fields, onSuccess, onError, options);
        }

        function onSuccess(contacts) {
            for (var i = 0; i < contacts.length; i++) {
                alert(contacts[i].displayName); //popup here comes once as null
            }
        }

        function onError(contactError) {
            alert('onError!');
        }
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding the below option worked for me. Apart from that, my existing code is fine. displayName works fine.

```
options.multiple=true;
```

Answer (score 1):

Try these code.. its working for me.

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
  <script src="cordova.js"></script>

document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);

                    function onDeviceReady(){
                        loadContacts();
                        }

                function loadContacts()
                {
                    var options = new ContactFindOptions();
                    options.filter="";
                    options.multiple=true;
                    filter = ["*"];
                    navigator.contacts.find(filter, onSuccess, onError, options);
                }

                function onSuccess(contacts) {
                    $('#getContactList').html('');
                    var listItem="";
                    //alert(contacts.length);
                    for (var i = 0; i < contacts.length; i++) {
                        //get name from contacts
                        alert(contacts[i].name.givenName) ;
                    }

                }
                function onError(contactError) {
                    alert('onError!');
                }
```

Comment: Can you plz explain how this is different from my code and what I am doing wrong?

Comment: its working for me. i was facing some issue when i was using "contacts[i].displayName", then changed to "contacts[i].name.givenName

Comment: Adding options.multiple=true; worked and all other code remains same.